# Site doesn't show up. Instead a bunch of weird characters?

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8, mojibake

```
‹�����í˜±jÃ0†w=Å=AÜ ÂÐƒ)ÅKGÅ:¢En%¹©ß¾²Ý 7xèpußøãŸ~ÝöÇ®Ömót¨•îŸû®©îao‚½‘Í:ºR†æk@´huõÃ(]­;z:¼•Íö¾þ{¥•‚¾ímwi£_±Ä1)–ÄÇ�‡‘,‰%Ž#YKF²Ä²Ä8ŒèKF²$–88ŒdI,qpÉ’Xâà0’%±Ä1Àaþe–TïÆOŒ@ 2^ßÇh"ù¦`Î!ëœ„yœ"Dü˜0e°Ó:ËË>e„ñÊˆfp.à(U®<œv¿ì;xñhRY3˜‹¡�ÞdŒ;Uºõ×R°WkÑ^Z÷¥¯Wß.Ò¤·��
```

That's exactly what shows up instead of my website in the web browser. Though on localhost the website works great. It's a Zend Framework based website, on localhost the output looks something like this (shortened version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US" />


</head>
<body>

<!--

LOTS OF HTML HERE

-->

</body>
</html>
```

What could cause this problem? It used to work before, this bug has only appeared today (or maybe already yesterday, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: Ha! This seems to be a chain reaction. Look at the last line of your response headers:

```
Date: Sun, 04 Apr 2010 17:06:39 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Etag: "17b7-4a7b64fa-0"
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Aug 2009 23:19:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 303

509 Bandwidth Limit ExceededContent-Encoding: gzip
```

The newline behind "509 bandwidth limit exceeded" seems to be missing. This seems to screw up the information about the content being gzipped. I'm guessing the garbage is the error message that gets displayed in case of exceeded bandwidth, which also explains why it's so small.

Comment: Hmm, I don't do any compression in the application nor does it use Zend_Cache.

Comment: @Richard really strange. Is there a live URL to look at by any chance? I don't think this is an encoding problem - not if the garbage shows up in one browser but not the other. Hmmm.

Comment: It's working from my end - you may want to change your db password though, as the auth details are there in plain site for all to read

Comment: And oh indeed yes, 1 round of password changes recommended :) The web root is mapped one directory too high.

Comment: It should be redirected with htaccess but that seems to have stopped working as well... thanks for noticing though.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the content-type meta tag which specifies UTF-8... it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the 'Accept-encoding' to null:

```
$client->setHeaders(array('Accept-encoding' => ''));
$client->request();
```

Hope it helps.